# Creating a new dataframe based on values of another dataframe's column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following:

[image]

```
Index   Fruit   ID
0   Apple   0.5
0   Apple   1
1   Orange  1.6
1   Orange  2
2   Banana  2.3
2   Banana  3
```

I would like to create a new dataframe based on the following algorithm: Take the first row that satisfies Index + 0.5 <= ID, add the row to new dataframe, otherwise next row. So the outcome should look like this:

[image]

I believe I can do this in a tedious and inefficient loop, but knowing pandas is very powerful (and I am very new to pandas), is there a more efficient way to create the dataframe?

Comment: Added text sdfsdfsdfsdf

Comment: New question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46948300/pandas-filtering-a-dataframe-by-index-of-another-dataframe-then-combine-the-t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, use `groupby` + `apply` + `head`:

```
(df.groupby('Index', group_keys=False)
   .apply(lambda x: x[x['Index'] + 0.5 <= x['ID']].head(1)))

   Index   Fruit   ID
0      0   Apple  0.5
2      1  Orange  1.6
5      2  Banana  3.0
```