# pandas - filtering a dataframe by index of another dataframe, then combine the two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes as the following:

```
df1 

Index   Fruit
1       Apple
2       Banana
3       Peach

df2 

Index   Taste
1       Tasty
1.5     Rotten
2       Tasty
2.6     Tasty
3       Rotten
3.3     Tasty
4       Tasty
```

I would like to filter df2 by using the indices of the two dataframes such that df1.index + 0.5 <= df2.index, and then take the first row of result. Then combine the two dataframes together.

The resulting dataframe should look like:

```
df_outcome          

Index   Fruit   Index_df2   Taste
1       Apple   1.5         Rotten
2       Banana  2.6         Tasty
3       Peach   4           Tasty
```

I tried doing the following `df2[df2.index>=df1.index + 0.5]` but it returns

> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

.

Any help?

Comment: Hi, do you mind doing a timeit test of both our solutions on your actual data?

Comment: Sure, but @jezrael, I get ValueError: Cannot shift with no freq when I try your code.

Comment: It seems like some bug, maybe need upgrade pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the rows from `df2`, use *numpy broadcasting* and `argmax`. Afterwards, concat the result with `df1` using `pd.concat`.

```
r = df2.iloc[(df1.Index.values + 0.5 
       <= df2.Index.values[:, None]).argmax(axis=0)].reset_index(drop=1)

pd.concat([df1, r], 1)

   Index   Fruit  Index   Taste
0      1   Apple    1.5  Rotten
1      2  Banana    2.6   Tasty
2      3   Peach    4.0   Tasty
```

---

**Details**

Broadcasting gives:

```
x = (df1.Index.values + 0.5 <= df2.Index.values[:, None])
array([[False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

And taking the `argmax` of this, you have:

```
x.argmax(axis=0)
array([1, 3, 6])
```

Comment: Performance in small data are not very nice, better is test in large data :(

Comment: @jezrael Maybe but in this case you know where it's going, search sorted is O(NLogN) which is slower by a log factor. Also I'm not sure how to scale this test to large data, doing pd.concat(df * 10000) won't give an adequate sample space to test the merit of either of these solutions.

Comment: You need create custom data, `pd.concat(df * 10000)` cannot be used, sure... But timings for small data is very bad idea, I think the best is remove it... Because in large data timings can be different (not sure in your solution, maybe timings show your solution is better in large data, I have no idea)

Comment: @jezrael  Okay, I'll make some custom data. But I won't remove this. There's nothing wrong with showing the timings for small datasets. If OP's data is small, it makes their choice simple. Give me some time and I'll ping you when done.

Comment: No, if add large data, no problem. But ily small data it is really bad :(

Comment: @jezrael I decided it was better to remove the performance stats and leave the testing to OP. It's possible your solution is faster on larger data, I'll leave it to OP.

Comment: Yes, so add it, please. Because I am curious. Or I am add it?

Comment: @jezrael The truth is... I tried to make some fake data. But when I test,  my answer gives segmentation fault while yours gives `IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds` XD I think argmax is slow on large data, also my solution creates a copy :)

Comment: So, if you want to add test, please do it.

Comment: Is there an more efficient way to do this? So right now my df2 has 10 million rows so it can take a while.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`searchsorted`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.searchsorted.html) for indices, then select by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and last [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df1.reset_index(), 
                df2.iloc[df2.index.searchsorted(df1.index + .5)].reset_index()], axis=1)
print (df)
   Index   Fruit  Index   Taste
0      1   Apple    1.5  Rotten
1      2  Banana    2.6   Tasty
2      3   Peach    4.0   Tasty
```

Detail:

```
print (df2.index.searchsorted(df1.index + .5))
[1 3 6]

print (df2.iloc[df2.index.searchsorted(df1.index + .5)])
        Taste
Index        
1.5    Rotten
2.6     Tasty
4.0     Tasty
```

Comment: Hi, please see comment on main question

Comment: I think is looks like bug, if dont help upgrade pandas use another solution.